# Where does the 2 come from in the force on the surface of a grounded sphere near a point charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors, coulombs-law

In section 2.2 of the classical text on electrodynamics by John David Jackson the method of images is exemplified with a grounded sphere in the presence of a conductor. In the end of the section, he calculates the electrostatic force acting on the charge and surface. This is first done by Coloumb's law, but Jackson notes that it can also be achieved by integration, which, he shows, gives the same result. The force on an area element $\mathrm{d}a$ is said to be $\frac{σ^2}{2ε_0}\mathrm{d}a$, where $σ$ is the induced surface charge, calculated from the potential.

Now, where does the $2$ come from? I understand the force could be obtained by integrating $E(x)\mathrm{d}q$, where $E(x)$ is the field. Of course $\mathrm{d}q=σ\,\mathrm{d}a$,  but since there is no field inside the conductor, isn't $E(X)=\frac{σ}{ε_0}$?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of dual area of surface. It has 2 sides and charges will appear on both back and front sides

Comment: Thanks for answering. But why should I consider both sides? I'm trying to calculate the force on an infinitesimal element of area, after which integration over the whole surface of the sphere is to be performed. Shouldn't that take care of both sides, since the "dual" area elementment will be integrated over as well?